# How to use method which takes object from onCreate as parameter in onPause method

Tags: android

I have an object created in onCreate method, and when an app is running it`s changing every 50ms and when an user closes an app I want to save this object to json file. I have a method for that, but it takes an object as a parameter. I thought to create another object in activity class in order to use it as a parameter in onPause method, but I have no idea how to clone object from onCreat before closing app. Do you have any idea?
Here is a code of method that saves object to a json file.

```
public void writeObject(coin coinObj) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(coinObj);
    prefsEditor.putString("myObject", json);
    Log.d("writeObject", "Has been saved successfully");
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: declare the object as a local variable

Comment: in this case, when I am reading object from a file, gson.fromJson (fromJson symbol cannot be resolved)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare your object as class member:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity 
{

  Coin coin;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    coin = new Coin();
 }
}
```

Then use onPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    writeObject(coin);
}
```